# Redirecting to a page with #placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a #placeholder in a page .I want to redirect to this page form a link that should take me to #placeholder  section.in firefox  this works fine,but in ie i am not getting  #placeholder

### my redirect logic

```
 - string path =
   HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl + 
   #placeholder; 
   Response.Redirect("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}",
   Server.Encode(path), Server.Encode(path))));
```

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it in your Response.Redirect:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}#{2}",
   Server.Encode(path), Server.Encode(path), placeholder))));
```

(FWIW: This is technically called an anchor)

Comment: @volpav Nicely spotted - coulda sworn that was in the original question.